# How do I keep the column names when I convert a pandas df to np array?

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

I need to convert a pandas df to np array, but I lose the column names in the process. I have read and googled for a while now and I'm stuck.

My df looks like this:

```
mont_data.tail()
Out[114]: 
Index        MOEX.ME     ^GSPC      ^MXX     ^N225    ^OSEAX
Date                                                        
2016-05-31  0.001482 -0.004077  0.002506 -0.000005  0.033240
2016-06-30  0.074850  0.008136 -0.002262 -0.029029  0.002518
2016-07-31  0.025882  0.030147  0.024242  0.007169  0.032473
2016-08-31  0.059069  0.014333  0.025050  0.025243 -0.008767
2016-09-30  0.035201 -0.009029 -0.016499 -0.039833 -0.003520
```

I then do:

```
mont_arr = mont_data.as_matrix(columns=[mont_data.columns[0:5]])
```

or:

```
mont_arr = mont_data.as_matrix(columns=[mont_data.columns[0:]])
```

Both result in a np array without column headers. Any idea how to solve this?

<sub>Using latest version of mentioned packages with Python 3.5</sub>

Comment: Can't do: `numpy` arrays do not have header names.

Comment: Hmmm...  I'm gonna do a np.corrcoef on the array, how can I keep track of the correlation coefficients when there ar no names attached to them?

Comment: `mont_data.columns.tolist()` will give you a list with your column names. But you can do the computation in pandas using [`DataFrame.corr()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the correlation coefficients between columns in pandas.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
Index        MOEX.ME     ^GSPC      ^MXX     ^N225    ^OSEAX
2016-05-31  0.001482 -0.004077  0.002506 -0.000005  0.033240
2016-06-30  0.074850  0.008136 -0.002262 -0.029029  0.002518
2016-07-31  0.025882  0.030147  0.024242  0.007169  0.032473
2016-08-31  0.059069  0.014333  0.025050  0.025243 -0.008767
2016-09-30  0.035201 -0.009029 -0.016499 -0.039833 -0.003520
''')
mont_data = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True).set_index('Date')

print(mont_data.corr())
```

Output:

```
          MOEX.ME     ^GSPC      ^MXX     ^N225    ^OSEAX
MOEX.ME  1.000000  0.201809  0.030481 -0.152252 -0.762061
^GSPC    0.201809  1.000000  0.853232  0.595998  0.261402
^MXX     0.030481  0.853232  1.000000  0.926106  0.231001
^N225   -0.152252  0.595998  0.926106  1.000000  0.225621
^OSEAX  -0.762061  0.261402  0.231001  0.225621  1.000000
```

Comment: ... or `mont_data.iloc[:, 1:].T.corr()` to reproduce the result of `np.corrcoef`

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
             MOEX.ME     ^GSPC      ^MXX     ^N225    ^OSEAX
Date
2016-05-31  0.001482 -0.004077  0.002506 -0.000005  0.033240
2016-06-30  0.074850  0.008136 -0.002262 -0.029029  0.002518
2016-07-31  0.025882  0.030147  0.024242  0.007169  0.032473
2016-08-31  0.059069  0.014333  0.025050  0.025243 -0.008767
2016-09-30  0.035201 -0.009029 -0.016499 -0.039833 -0.003520

In [23]: result = pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(df), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)

In [24]: result
Out[24]:
          MOEX.ME     ^GSPC      ^MXX     ^N225    ^OSEAX
MOEX.ME  1.000000 -0.087534  0.433865 -0.651299  0.093799
^GSPC   -0.087534  1.000000  0.457119  0.657940  0.980054
^MXX     0.433865  0.457119  1.000000 -0.299503  0.596537
^N225   -0.651299  0.657940 -0.299503  1.000000  0.501435
^OSEAX   0.093799  0.980054  0.596537  0.501435  1.000000
```

Comment: I then get the following error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (121, 121), indices imply (5, 121)

Comment: Now I get: Shape of passed values is (121, 121), indices imply (5, 5)

Comment: Careful! By default, `numpy.corrcoef()` computes correlation between rows --- you need to specify `rowvar=0` to get correlation between columns.

Comment: Right you are! This works: R = pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(df, rowvar=0), index=df.columns, columns=df.columns). Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @cJc, you can accept only one answer as a correct one, and Alberto's answer is definitely the better one, so please accept his answer. ;)

Comment: @MaxU: that's very chivalrous of you. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso, nothing special, it's just fair as your answer is much more precise and neat :)